# Jackson2HttpMessageConverter perfomance issue

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I have endpoint for post requests. Getting comlplex object in body (with nested subvobjects and collections of subvobjects). When sending small body everything works fine, when sending large objects it gets stuck. I've tried to debug and found that stuck in messageConverter when trying convert from json to object. I'm using default Jackson2HttpMessageConverter.
Target object is generated from yaml by openvapi generator.

CPU utilizes 1 thread by 100%, memory consumption growing up to 1.5GB then stops growing. Tried on different environments.

SpringBoot 2.6.3

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: how big is your request body ?

Comment: 15 Megabytes, not very large

Comment: I doubt cause is due to request converter, how could you judge that ?

Comment: I’ve followed the execution by idea debugger